# Null pointer Exception at runtime while running a JDO based program

Tags: java, jdo

We are getting a Null pointer Exception at runtime while running a JDO based program.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextPool.checkOut(ExecutionContextPool.java:97)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.getExecutionContext(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:1130)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.<init>(JDOPersistenceManager.java:143)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.newPM(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:853)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:832)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:813)
```

We are using JDO 4.0. 
Scenario is : That application works flawlessly for some time but then after some time, during the running process we encounter the Nullpointer Exception.

What are the possible solution for the same.
PMF is being Created using the Spring.

```
<!--PersistenceManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="pmf" class="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="schema" value="PROVISIONING" />
        <property name="persistenceProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="datanucleus.metadata.supportORM" value="true" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.autoCreateTables" value="true" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.autoCreateColumns" value="true" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.autoCreateConstraints" value="true" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="false" />
                <entry key="javax.jdo.mapping.Schema" value="PROVISIONING" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.manageRelationshipsChecks" value="true" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.identifier.case" value="UpperCase" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.validateTables" value="false" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.validateConstraints" value="false" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.validateColumns" value="false" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.rdbms.CheckExistTablesOrViews" value="false" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.rdbms.initializeColumnInfo" value="None" />
                <entry key="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="h2" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="rdbms" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.Multithreaded" value="true" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.metadata.allowAnnotations" value="false" />
                <entry key="datanucleus.enableStatistics" value="true" />
            </map>

        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: there is no such thing as JDO 4.0. There is JDO 3.0, 3.1. There is DataNucleus 4.0, 4.1, 4.2. Define what version of what you are using

Comment: First you say that this NullPointer is thrown "at runtime" but then you followup by saying that at first it runs flawlessly for some time and the error occurs after a while. What is "some time" ? There has to be an action that causes the program to throw the error, try and narrow down when exactly the error occurs. Run the program in debug mode and follow step by step everything that ahppens until the error is thrown. Only then will you be able to solve it. Based on the code you provided it's impossible to tell what is causing the issue.

Comment: Its DataNucleus 4.0.

Comment: we are running our component inside the Websphere Application Server 8.5. On EAR startup the application comes up smoothly and no exception is reported at the startup. But after running for 2 -3 Days and one time even a Month of running it suddenly starts throwing the Nullpointer exception during code execution. Though we tried to find the core reason several times. If we look at Datanucleus code inside the class :  ExecutionContextPool . The code at line # 97 is just  expire(ec); which is empty function. Why it is throwing Nullpointer exception we are unable to understand and locate.

Comment: I said define what version. "4.0" says it is this series of releases. 4.0.0.release, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, etc ... and what jars?

Comment: Hi Neil -  The version Being used is: 4.0.0

Comment: You mean 4.0.0.release? because there is no 4.0.0. And why would you use 4.0.0.release when there are many later releases ... even in 4.0 series ... up to 4.0.7

Comment: Hi Neil -> This is production issue changing Version won't be feasible.

Comment: Hi, Is the changing Version only solution for the above problem. What is the actual reason as to when this occurs.

Comment: nobody can answer that since you haven't identified the problem. You can easily enough look at the actual code for whatever version you are using (still undefined) and see the line where you have NPE and work out why, then look at later versions code and see if they are the same.